# Call if statement within html class

Tags: php, html, css, dynamic, navigation

I'm trying to create a dynamic nav where a simple if statement is used to check if the current page equals the current url.This will echo "selected" within the html class if these things match up. When I test my code I see that the whole php statement prints out with the html. What am I missing or is this possible the way I'm trying to go about it?

-thank you

```
<?php
    $menu = array(
        'home' => array('text' => 'home', 'url' => '/'),
        'about'  => array('text' => 'about',  'url' => '/about'),
        'contact' => array('text' => 'contact', 'url' => '/contact'),
    );

    $navbar = "navbar";

    function GenerateMenu($items, $class) {

        $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $selected = "selected";

        $html = "<nav class = '$class'>\n";

        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {

            $html .= "\t<a id = '{$item['text']}' class = '<?php if(preg_match({$item['url']}, $currentpage)) echo $selected; ?> ' href = '{$item['url']}'> {$item['text']} ";
        }
        $html .= "</a>\n"
            . "</nav>\n";


        return $html;

    };
    echo GenerateMenu($menu, $navbar);

    ?>
```

Comment: You have written <?php .... ?> inside php code.

Comment: generating html in php is bad practice.

Comment: Please provide more details like file name, the server you are using and if possible some code above and below your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a working solution.

```
<?php
$menu = array(
    'home' => array('text' => 'home', 'url' => '/'),
    'about'  => array('text' => 'about',  'url' => '/about/'),
    'contact' => array('text' => 'contact', 'url' => '/contact/'),
);

$navbar = "navbar";

function GenerateMenu($items, $class) {

    $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


    $html = "<nav class = '$class'>\n";

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        //$selected = (preg_match('$item['url']', $currentpage)) ? 'selected' : null;
        if($item['url'] == $currentpage)
        {
            $selected = 'selected';
        }
        else
        {
            $selected = " ";
        }
        $html .= "\t<a id = '{$item['text']}' class = '{$selected}' href = '{$item['url']}'> {$item['text']} ";
    }
    $html .= "</a>\n"
        . "</nav>\n";


    return $html;

};
echo GenerateMenu($menu, $navbar);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below code:

```
<?php
    $menu = array(
        'home' => array('text' => 'home', 'url' => '/'),
        'about'  => array('text' => 'about',  'url' => '/about'),
        'contact' => array('text' => 'contact', 'url' => '/contact'),
    );

    $navbar = "navbar";

    function GenerateMenu($items, $class) {

        $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        $html = "<nav class = '".$class."'>\n";

        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
            $selected = (preg_match({$item['url']}, $currentpage)) ? "selected" : "";
            $html .= "\t<a id = '".{$item['text']}."' class = '".$selected."' href = '".{$item['url']}."'> ".{$item['text']}." </a>\n";
        }

        $html .= "</nav>\n";

        return $html;

    };

    echo GenerateMenu($menu, $navbar);

    ?>
```

Comment: this calls a parse error where you declared selected, does it work on your end?

Comment: @XavierGilmore How can i execute your code at my end, varies i have no full code of yours. So i just update the bugs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$html .= "\t<a id = '{$item['text']}' class = '".if(preg_match({$item['url']}, $currentpage)) echo $selected;."' href = '{$item['url']}'> {$item['text']} ";
```

and for the applying active class why don't you use jquery like below..

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;

   $('#nav').find('a').each(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).attr('href') == loc);
  });
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I don't think it's worth it to import a whole frame work to accomplish one thing. Though it does feel like javascript is going to be less of a headache.

Comment: okey its your decision to do or not to do.. that's only a suggestion.
but in big project it may become very fast so worthy to use. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this

```
function GenerateMenu($items, $class) {

    $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $html = "<nav class = '$class'>\n";

    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {

        $selected = '';
        if(preg_match({$item['url']}, $currentpage))
        {
            $selected = "selected";
        }

        $html .= "\t<a id='{$item['text']}' class='{$selected}' href='{$item['url']}'> {$item['text']} ";
    }
    $html .= "</a>\n"
        . "</nav>\n";


    return $html;
};
```